# How do I make my method count the character of 'a' in the main char array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, char, chararray

This was a problem involving an array of chars and uses recursion. I understand partly how to solve it, but I can't seem to output how many times the char `a` appears in the char array. Here is the method that I came up with two variations I tried but to no success.

```java
private static Int charCount(char[] test, int i, char c) {
       
       int[] number = new int[26];
       
       char c = 'a';
       
       if (test.length == 0) {
              return 0;
            }
            int count = 0;
            if (test == a) {
              count++;
            }
            return count + count(test[1], a);
          }
 
       for(c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
       {
           for( char x : test )
           {
               if( c == x )
               {
                   c++;
                   
               }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I understand this, but let me know if I don't. Your question is: How can I read the number of a value in an array? Correct? If so then here is some code which should work:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HowToReadCountOfDataInArray {
  private static final char[] arr = newArr();

  private static int ReadArrayValue(char[] arr, char value) {
      int count = 0;
    
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if(arr[i] == value) {
              count++;
          }
      }
    
      return count;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(ReadArrayValue(arr, 'a'));
      System.out.println(arr);
  }
}
```

P.S. Here is the "newArr()" method:

```
public static char[] newArr() {
    char[] arr = new char[new Random().nextInt(100 + 1 - 1) + 1];
    int aOrB = new Random().nextInt(2 + 1 - 1) + 1;
        
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        aOrB = new Random().nextInt(2 + 1 - 1) + 1;
        
        if(aOrB == 1) {
            arr[i] = 'a';
        }else if(aOrB == 2) {
            arr[i] = 'b';
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```